# YouTube video doesn't stop despite end-parameter in url

Tags: youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZOgdS5LhSQ&start=93&end=105

Why doesn't stop this video playing at 1:45? Starting at 1:33 works fine.

I'm using it as a embedded link in a company website.

Comment: Try using embed `https://www.youtube.com/embed/DZOgdS5LhSQ?start=93&end=105`

Comment: Thanks. Can you change your comment to an answer please, so I can reply and/or check it 'answered'.

Comment: It works, but not when pasting it in a WordPress-page, WP deletes the start/stop params.

Comment: I dunno about wordpress. Hope someone can help you on this

Comment: Can you elaborate on "DZOgdS5LhSQ" @SauminiNavaratnam pls

Answer (score 0):

YouTube embedding demands some specific [URL query parameters](https://www.semrush.com/blog/url-parameters/) and html attributes in the iframe element. The easiest way to get the proper link is to share->embed->copy embed code on youtube itself.

In your case, the embed element you're looking for is this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DZOgdS5LhSQ?&start=93&end=105" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The embed url uses a different endpoint and query parameters than a regular youtube video link. For example, the `start` and `end` parameters works for the `https://youtube.com/embed/[videoId]?start=[start_seconds]&end=[end_seconds]` endpoint but if you paste that endpoint link with those parameters directly as a URL on the browser, youtube will redirect you to `https://youtube.com/watch?v=[videoId]&t=[start_seconds]s` and completely disregard your `end` parameter.

I deducted you may be using Wordpress' built-in HTML Editor to embed the video, where it only asks the URL from you. What happens there is that YouTube servers interpret it as a regular browser request and convert it to the `https://youtube.com/watch` endpoint that doesn't have an `end` parameter.

If you want to embed your video with start and end times you need to edit the html in the Worpress text editor and copy the iframe element where you want to put it. Just make sure to adjust the `width` and `height` attributes to your linking

To answer Austin Dean's question in the comments, "DZOgdS5LhSQ" is the Id for that video. It goes in the `v` query parameter in the `https://youtube.com/watch` endpoint and as the path after the `https://youtube.com/embed/` endpoint folled by the query parameters